# OpenCV LBP recognizer on MNIST digits - haarcascade?

Tags: opencv

I am trying to implement the OpenCV `LBPHFaceRecognizer()` and make it work for the images of digits from the MNIST dataset. These images are 28 x 28 px and look like this:

[image]

But for this task I need an haarcascade.xml file which is able to recognize digits. In the OpenCV package I only find xml files which are suited for facerecognition and russian plate numbers.

Here is my [code](https://codeshare.io/cVJ0d), I basicly just need to replace the `cascadePath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"` with an apropriate xml for digits, but where do I get one?

All in all I want to test facerecognition with numbers instead of faces. So an input image where a "1" is shown should be able to recognize all other "1"`s in the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need to train a cascade. Here two link to explain how to do this :

[1](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html) This is the Opencv documentation for opencv_traincascade which is the opencv app to train cascade (generate .xml)

[2](http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html) This is a useful tutorial to train cascade with opencv. It explains what to do and give some tricks to generate input file.